# What is this bright yellow daylily with six narrow petals that curl at the ends?

Tags: identification, perennials, wildflowers

I have a number of varieties of daylilies in a wildflower garden in Massachusetts, USA, zone 6a. There are at least five, although some may be the same variety in different colors. They were all here when we bought the house four years ago. I'd like to start identifying some, especially since they're not the usual ones I see around the neighborhood.

This is one I haven't seen anywhere else, and I think it's unique and beautiful. It's bright yellow, with six long, narrow petals, which taper to a point at the end. Some of the leaves curl around in a twirling fashion.

To clarify, only the long, narrow, grass-like leaves in the pictures belong to the daylily. They're most visible in the lower right and corner of the picture on the left, and the lower left part of the picture on the right. The big green and all other leaves belong to other things. I know the leaves aren't easy to see, so I'm hoping the identification can be made by the flower.

What is this daylily called?

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of varieties of Hemerocallis - this is one of the so called 'spider' daylilies, which have thinner petals which often reflex or twist. I can see a sort of slight difference in colour, with a couple of longitudinal stripes or ridges, most noticeable on the lower right petal in the right hand picture, so I think this one is probably Hemerocallis 'Kindly Light' as you can see [here](http://www.daylilies.org/DaylilyDB/detail.php?id=27571&name=Kindly%20Light).